# when I defined a property in appdelegate, how to use it?

Tags: ios, properties

I have a global property defined in appdelegate, in the other view controllers, I need to use it many times.

In specific viewcontorller, I have two ways

1) define some local variables, and use.
2) define a class variable, and use.

which way is recommended?

Comment: Option 1 is safer if the value is dynamic - ie. it could change during the lifetime of your object (something like your GPS location).  Option 2 if it is relatively static (say a NSManagedObjectContext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a constant for getting your main app delegate, then use the delegate to access whatever you require -

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] -> this will fetch you app delegate.
```

Now define a constant somewhere global in your app -

```
#define APP_DELEGATE [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

Now use this constant to get the properties across the app -

```
APP_DELEGATE.prop -> this will fetch properties of delegate.
```